# Array of bytes: how to know exactly numbers of byte received

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using array of bytes to store data packet received from another computer.

```
receivedData = new byte[1024];
receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
socket.receive(receivedPacket);
receivedData = receivedPacket.getData();
String res = new String(receivedData);  // PROBLEM HERE
```

the problem is at last line: because I declare `receivedData` as a byte stream with length 1024. so, always last line will create a new string from whole array, although it doesn't know exactly how many real byte I received. So, I meet frustrated error: `res` is not received as I wish. (because length of real bytes that I received not fix whole array)

So, my question is: how can I fix this point, how can I know how many bytes I really received to convert to string?

Comment: Initially I think you can put the receivedPacket into an object and then create the byte array based on the length of the object being cast to byte[]. After that create the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `DatagramPacket.getLength()`.

```
receivedData = new byte[1024];
receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
socket.receive(receivedPacket);
receivedData = receivedPacket.getData();
String charsetName = "US-ASCII"; // set to desired charset
String res = new String(receivedData, 0, receivedPacket.getLength(), charsetName);
```

Edited to add charset.  Thanks, [parsifal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919251/parsifal).

Comment: Note that this relies on default encoding when creating the string, which can be a source of hard-to-resolve bugs.

Answer (score 2):

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive%28java.net.DatagramPacket%29) for `DatagramSocket.receive()`:

> The length field of the datagram packet object contains the length of
>   the received message

You can then construct your `String` using the constructor that takes a byte array and offsets.

Answer (score 2):

Call [DatagramPacket.getLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getLength%28%29) to find out how many bytes were actually received.

And when you construct the `String` from those bytes, *be sure to specify the encoding* (as it is, you're using the JDK default encoding, which may differ from the server's encoding).